# Как сделать авторизацию по qr как в whatsapp?

Tags: python, django, flutter, dart, qrcode

*(я новичок)* Я бы хотел сделать приложение на flutter в который надо будет зарегистрироваться и там будут опеределенные данные(взятые и отданные книги). Там же сделать сделать qr сканер.

есть полка с книгами на который можно получить доступ только если отсканировать qr на компьтере(qr будет не постоянным и будет обонавляться каждую 1 минуту ради безопастности)  и обозначать какие книги вы взяли и какие вы оставили. Данные будут отображаться на телефоне у клиента(тоесть приложение на телефоне клиента не имеет никакого функиционала кроме просмотра данных о книгах)
(серверную часть хочу написать на питоне)

**вопрос: как авторизоваться через qr? а точнее как отправлять данные при сканировке qr?**

я знаю что qr хранит небольшие данные. насколько я понимаю я должен буду сделать генератор qr кода который будет хранит ключ доступа(к сожалению я так же не понимаю как реалзовать ключ доступа к аккаунтам и будет ли безопасно сделать ключ доступа с помощью которого можно получить доступ ко всем аккаунтам) допустим qr хранит определенный ключ(1234) при сканировке приложение должно отправлять example.com/qr/1234, но **как обратиться к нужному аккаунту?**.

**Есть ли более эффективные способы реализации этого и какие ресурсы вы посоветуете для изучения?**

Answer (score 0):

в клиенте лучше делать например через POST запрос а в qr шифровать md5
например: сегоднешняя дата+ид+логин+предыдущий хеш это в md5 а со стороны серва проверять хеш
с этого получаем временной хэш

Comment: не совсем понимаю на счет шифрования в qr ид логина и сегоднящней даты. Зачем их превращать в qr code

Comment: Вопрос в том будет ли свой клиент, если да, то на событии отсканировании можно сделать POST на сервер с данными QR и сервер их отработает, и клиент получает ответ

Comment: я так понимаю под клиентом вы подразумеваете свое приложение для сканирования, если оно так, то да. Я собираюсь хранить ключ доступа в qr code и при сканировании отправлять запрос на сервер с данными из авторизованного акканута.

Comment: Qr код можно сделать просто индефикатор книги, а приложение его будет сканировать и от пользователя отправлятся запрос на сервер с ид книги и данными полльзователя, то-есть если через обычный сканер то он покажет циферки, а через приложение авторизовать пользователя

Comment: Статейка с примером чтения и генерации qr: https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/generate-read-qr-code-python

Comment: я хочу реализовать это немного по другому у меня будет шкаф с отсеками и у каждого отсека будет свой ид и на целевом устройстве будет спрашивать какой отсек открыть и по нему будет зачисляться книга